# How to unmount an image in mac using actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, macos, air, dmg

I am developing an AIR application in Flex. This deals with mounting images using .dmg files. After finishing the work with it, the program has to unmount it.

I am able to mount the .dmg using the DiskImageMounter utility by passing the path to dmg file as argument. I would like to know how do I unmount the image programatically. Please help..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

in Terminal, you can unmount a .dmg with this command:

```
> diskutil unmount /Volumes/DMG_NAME
```

so pass "unmount /Volumes/DMG_NAME" as an argument to diskutil using native process.